# ServerAlias not catching not FQDN domain name

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2

I got the following setup with a docker front reverse proxy

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName glpi1.domain.com
    ServerAlias glpi1.domain.com glpi1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



    ProxyPass               /       http://glpi1:80

    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://glpi1:80  
...
```

(The ServerAlias has a duplicate of ServerName, that's cause I'm lazy at scripting)

This is working when I reach http://glpi1.domain.com but not working with http://glpi1

Instead, I end up on the default vhost :

```
DocumentRoot /dev/null
<Directory /dev/null>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cat` display was ok, `nano` too, but when I `vim`'d in the file found that :

```
ServerName glpi1.domain.com^M
ServerAlias glpi1.domain.com glpi1
```

The error came from a `sed` in my script where I used `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Now apache forwards everything neatly.